# Object to Array Conversion giving weird result

Tags: php, arrays, object, type-conversion

I am trying to convert class to array. I am using following code:

```
class Abc{
    private $x, $y, $z;
    protected $x1, $y1, $z1;
    protected $x2, $y2, $z2;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->x=$this->y=$this->z=$this->x1=$this->y1=$this->z1=$this->x2=$this->y2=$this->z2=0;
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $x;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        return (array)$this;
    }
}
$abc = new Abc();
echo '<pre>', print_r($abc->toArray(), true), '</pre>';
```

Now the weird thing is the output:

```
Array
(
    [Propertyx] => 0
    [Propertyy] => 0
    [Propertyz] => 0
    [*x1] => 0
    [*y1] => 0
    [*z1] => 0
    [*x2] => 0
    [*y2] => 0
    [*z2] => 0
)
```

I want clean keys with no `Class` name and no * before key names.

Can anyone suggest me how to convert members names into array keys without class name and and without (*). Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: the main problem is `print_r`, as the OP use `true` in `print_r`, the `print_r` display the information with the array.

Comment: print_r will return the result instead of sending it to std Output when you pass second parameter true, that why I have added true.

Answer (score 3):

there is the special function

```
public function toArray() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

result

```
<pre>Array
(
    [x] => 0
    [y] => 0
    [z] => 0
    [x1] => 0
    [y1] => 0
    [z1] => 0
    [x2] => 0
    [y2] => 0
    [z2] => 0
)
</pre>
```

[demo](https://eval.in/573638)